# Can the fan in an iMac (model 5,1 "Late 2006") be replaced?

Tags: imac, repair

I have a 21" iMac model identifier `imac5,1` (Late 2006). (It's the one with a 2.16 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo and a max of 4 GB RAM, 3 GB addressable. You know, the white LCD ones)

Starting this weekend after I cleaned it... probably too aggressively... by vacuuming the exhaust slits and air intakes, it is now making a grinding / whirring noise. I suspect is is the case exhaust fan.

The temperature in the iMac seems okay, but I don't push it very hard so I am not sure if it will eventually fail due to heat. I do know that the noise is very annoying. Either way I would like to solve the problem.

Can the fan in an iMac (Late 2006) be replaced? I'm fairly certain it's not user servicable, however I could try it if it's possible without requiring special tools / training. I'd also be happy to pay to have it replaced but I don't even know if this is a service that's available for a 5 year old machine...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about replacing the fan, but with [XRG](http://www.gauchosoft.com/Software/X%20Resource%20Graph/) you can monitor your system's temperatures on screen.  [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?p=207) lets you tweak your fan speeds; maybe you can use it to dislodge whatever's in there, before you try opening the box.

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried smcFanControl and it seems to have no effect on fan speeds whatsoever...

Comment: I have been monitoring the temperature with Temperature Monitor, and the CPU code is ~120°F or ~50°C

Comment: 60 degC is about the hottest we can touch without getting burned. My (admittedly unproven) rule of thumb is that a device running at less that that isn't in danger from heat. Also, I have an iMac 24" of a similar vintage whose fans don't seem to ever react to increased temperatures. I use smcFanControl to bump them up 500 to 1000 RPM each when I'm playing a flash game. On my machine, the power supply and the GPU diode sensors are always the hottest ones. I picked values that would keep them at or below 60 degC.

Answer (score 1):

The fan *can* be replaced. However, as was already pointed out by the OP, Apple's disposable desktops usually do not have that many user-serviceable parts inside.

It can be done by private individuals, or by a service technician, even today, although by now the financial incentives in doing such a thing are strongly on the side of do-it-yourself.

Finding the proper replacement parts might also be not very cost effective.

If anyone wants to attempt this user-unfriendly and difficult procedure, here are the guides to do so:

from [ifixit.com:](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel_17%22)  (since link-only answers are discouraged and also to give anyone a first impression of all the convoluted steps necessary, here is the content of the page for a hard drive fan replacement, quoted without pictures)

> iMac Intel 17" Hard Drive Fan Replacement Written By: Walter Galan
>   (and 4 other contributors) Difficulty: Difficult
>
> Steps  37  /  Time Required ??
>
> Introduction
>
> Replacing a defective fan is pretty easy and will keep your iMac
>   running cool.
>
> Tools Buy these tools Phillips #1 Screwdriver Plastic Cards Spudger
>   T10 Torx Screwdriver T6 Torx Screwdriver T8 Torx Screwdriver
>
> iMac G5 17" 1.9 GHz/iMac Intel 17" (EMC No. 2104/2114) Hard Drive Fan
>   $19.95
>   **Step 1** Access Door Loosen the two captive Phillips screws
>   securing the access door to the iMac.
>
> Loosen the two captive Phillips screws securing the access door to the
>   iMac. Remove the access door from the iMac. Before beginning the
>   repair, unplug the computer and press and hold the power switch for
>   20-30 seconds, to discharge internal capacitors.  4 comments
>
> **Step 2** Front Bezel Remove the following four screws: Remove the
>   following four screws: Three 6 mm T8 Torx. One 8 mm T8 Torx.  2
>   comments
>
> **Step 3** Flip your iMac over and lay it stand-side down on a flat
>   surface.
>
> Flip your iMac over and lay it stand-side down on a flat surface. To
>   lift the front bezel off the iMac, simultaneously: Use your thumbs to
>   press in the RAM arms and hold the iMac down. Use your index fingers
>   to pull the small bridge of material on the front bezel toward
>   yourself. Pull the Front bezel up with your index fingers. Once the
>   small bridge of material has cleared the RAM arms, lift the front
>   bezel by its lower edge just enough to clear the bottom edge of the
>   rear case.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 4** Re-orient your iMac so it sits upright on the stand.
>
> Re-orient your iMac so it sits upright on the stand. Insert a plastic
>   card up into the corner of the air vent slot near the top of the rear
>   case. Push the card toward the top of the iMac to release the front
>   bezel latch. Pull the front bezel away from the rear case. Repeat this
>   process for the other side of the front bezel. It may be necessary to
>   apply several layers of duct tape to the top of the access card to aid
>   in releasing the latches. If the bezel refuses to release, try
>   pressing the lower edge back onto the rear case and repeat this
>   opening process.  6 comments
>
> **Step 5** Lay your iMac stand-side down on a table. Lay your iMac
>   stand-side down on a table. Lift the front bezel from its lower edge
>   and rotate it away from the rest of your iMac, minding the RAM arms
>   that may get caught. Lay the front bezel above the rest of the iMac. 
>   One comment
>
> **Step 6** If necessary, remove the piece of kapton tape(it is ok to toss
>   this) wrapped around the microphone and camera cables. If necessary,
>   remove the piece of kapton tape(it is ok to toss this) wrapped around
>   the microphone and camera cables.  2 comments
>
> **Step 7** Disconnect both the camera and microphone cables.
>
> Disconnect both the camera and microphone cables.  2 comments
>
> **Step 8** Display Peel up the lower EMI shield from the rear case. Peel
>   up the lower EMI shield from the rear case. It is only necessary to
>   peel the shield up from three sides. Leave it attached to the display.
>   We have found it helpful to tape the EMI shield against the display to
>   keep it out of the way.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 9** Remove the two 4.8 mm T6 Torx screws securing the display data
>   cable to the logic board.
>
> Remove the two 4.8 mm T6 Torx screws securing the display data cable
>   to the logic board. Grab the display data cable connector by its black
>   tab and pull it straight up off the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 10** Inverter cable on 24inch iMac pulls off to the left. Inverter
>   cable on 24inch iMac pulls off to the left. Pull the inverter cable
>   connector straight up off its socket on the logic board.  3 comments
>
> **Step 11** Peel back the aluminum EMI tape from the two vertical edges of
>   the display. Peel back the aluminum EMI tape from the two vertical
>   edges of the display. During reassembly, it is helpful to use several
>   small strips of tape to hold the EMI shielding along the left and
>   right edges of the display footprint out of the way before lowering
>   the display into the rear case of your iMac.  3 comments
>
> **Step 12** Allow the EMI shield to hang down from the display.
>
> TOOLS USED ON THIS STEP: TR10 Torx Security Screwdriver $5.95
>
> Allow the EMI shield to hang down from the display. Remove the four 8
>   mm with 2 mm thick head coarse-thread T10 Torx screws securing the
>   display to the rear case. These screws are recessed, so a thin
>   screwdriver such as this is essential for removal. Bit drivers tend to
>   be too short for this application. It is strongly recommended to use a
>   magnetized screwdriver so the screws won't fall into the iMac.  6
>   comments
>
> **Step 13** Lift the display from its lower edge and pull it toward
>   yourself to peel off the EMI shield attached to its top edge. Lift the
>   display from its lower edge and pull it toward yourself to peel off
>   the EMI shield attached to its top edge. Be mindful of any cables that
>   may get caught during removal.  One comment
>
> **Step 14** Speakers Remove the 30 mm T10 Torx screw securing the left
>   speaker to the rear case. Remove the 30 mm T10 Torx screw securing the
>   left speaker to the rear case.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 15** Remove the 17 mm T10 Torx screw from the right speaker. Remove
>   the 17 mm T10 Torx screw from the right speaker.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 16** Pull the SATA data cable connector away from its socket on the
>   logic board.
>
> TOOLS USED ON THIS STEP: Metal Spudger $2.95 Pull the SATA data cable
>   connector away from its socket on the logic board. The SATA connector
>   on most iMacs tends to stick in its socket on the logic board. If you
>   are having trouble disconnecting the SATA cable, insert a metal
>   spudger or any other thin tool into the gap between the SATA connector
>   and its socket and twist the spudger's shaft to safely separate the
>   two pieces.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 17** Disconnect the CPU fan by pulling its connector up off the
>   logic board. Disconnect the CPU fan by pulling its connector up off
>   the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 18** Disconnect the hard drive power cable by pulling its connector
>   up off the logic board. Disconnect the hard drive power cable by
>   pulling its connector up off the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 19** Use the flat end of a spudger to pry the AirPort Extreme
>   antenna connector up off the AirPort Extreme card. Use the flat end of
>   a spudger to pry the AirPort Extreme antenna connector up off the
>   AirPort Extreme card.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 20** If necessary, remove any tape covering the left speaker cable.
>   If necessary, remove any tape covering the left speaker cable.  Add a
>   comment
>
> **Step 21** Lift the left and right speakers out of the rear case.
>
> Lift the left and right speakers out of the rear case. The speaker
>   cables are still attached to the logic board. The right speaker cable
>   may be routed under the power button cable or the CPU fan cable (or
>   both). If so, disconnect both cables by pulling their connectors away
>   from the face of the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 22** Disconnect the speaker cable connector by pulling its
>   connector away from the socket on the logic board. Disconnect the
>   speaker cable connector by pulling its connector away from the socket
>   on the logic board. Pull the connector parallel to the face of the
>   logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 23** Logic Board Pull the power button cable connector up off its
>   socket on the logic board. Pull the power button cable connector up
>   off its socket on the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 24** Disconnect the ambient light sensor by pulling its connector
>   up off the socket on the logic board. Disconnect the ambient light
>   sensor by pulling its connector up off the socket on the logic board. 
>   Add a comment
>
> **Step 25** Disconnect the following four connectors by pulling them
>   straight away from their sockets: Disconnect the following four
>   connectors by pulling them straight away from their sockets: Camera
>   cable. Microphone cable. Optical drive fan cable. Hard drive fan
>   cable.  One comment
>
> **Step 26** Disconnect the optical drive thermal sensor cable from its
>   socket on the logic board. Disconnect the optical drive thermal sensor
>   cable from its socket on the logic board.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 27** Remove the two 7 mm fine thread T10 Torx screws securing the
>   optical drive clip to the logic board. Remove the two 7 mm fine thread
>   T10 Torx screws securing the optical drive clip to the logic board.
>   Remove the optical drive clip.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 28** Squeeze the two optical drive bracket ears together while
>   pulling the drive up toward yourself.
>
> Squeeze the two optical drive bracket ears together while pulling the
>   drive up toward yourself. It may be helpful to hold the logic board
>   down near the optical drive connector when pulling the drive toward
>   yourself to avoid both components lifting together. Pull the optical
>   drive away from the side of the rear case and remove it from the iMac.
>   If your optical drive is particularly stubborn to remove, try the
>   method used in the optical drive guide from the A1144 G5 iMac.  2
>   comments
>
> **Step 29** De-route the bundle of power supply cables from behind the
>   hard drive bracket. De-route the bundle of power supply cables from
>   behind the hard drive bracket. Some logic boards can be removed
>   without taking out the hard drive.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 30** Press the hard drive bracket down to free it from the rear
>   case, then rotate the top of the drive toward yourself. Press the hard
>   drive bracket down to free it from the rear case, then rotate the top
>   of the drive toward yourself. Pressing the top of the hard drive
>   bracket down to release it from the rear case requires a substantial
>   amount of force, so we recommend laying your iMac stand-side down on a
>   table to avoid knocking it over.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 31** Lift the hard drive (with cables attached) straight up off its
>   lower pins and remove it from the rear case. Lift the hard drive (with
>   cables attached) straight up off its lower pins and remove it from the
>   rear case. Be mindful of the hard drive cables, as they may catch on
>   the logic board during removal.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 32** Unplug the power supply cable bundle from the logic board by
>   simultaneously depressing the locking mechanism (toward yourself) with
>   a spudger and pulling the connector away from its socket. Unplug the
>   power supply cable bundle from the logic board by simultaneously
>   depressing the locking mechanism (toward yourself) with a spudger and
>   pulling the connector away from its socket. The locking mechanism
>   faces the rear case.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 33** Remove the following six screws securing the logic board to
>   the rear case: Remove the following six screws securing the logic
>   board to the rear case: Three fine-thread 7 mm T10 Torx. Three
>   coarse-thread 7 mm T10 Torx.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 34** Be sure to touch the chassis before proceeding to discharge
>   any static. Be sure to touch the chassis before proceeding to
>   discharge any static. Grab the logic board from its left edge and
>   rotate it out from the rear case, using your other hand to press the
>   RAM arms in enough to clear the rear case. Be mindful of the ports
>   attached to the rear of the logic board as they may stick to the rear
>   case.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 35** Pull the logic board straight out of the rear case, minding
>   any cables that may get caught. Pull the logic board straight out of
>   the rear case, minding any cables that may get caught.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 36** Optical Drive Fan Pull the optical drive fan off the posts
>   protruding from the rear case and lift it out of rear case, de-routing
>   cables as necessary. Pull the optical drive fan off the posts
>   protruding from the rear case and lift it out of rear case, de-routing
>   cables as necessary.  Add a comment
>
> **Step 37** Hard Drive Fan Pull the hard drive fan away from the rear
>   case. If necessary, de-route the cables from under the chassis.